# Connect to JDBC using integrated security and specifying username and password

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, tomcat8

I need to connect to SQL Server using a Windows Authentication user by specifying username and password in the connection string.

Somehow I need to make a connection  like this to work:

```
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.48.61\\sqlexpress2008r2;
databaseName=MyTestDatabase;integratedSecurity=true;
username=mydomain\eric;password=mypwd
```

Since the requirement seems odd I try to  exlpain my scenario:

- in my application the users are mapped to SQL Server users (either using sql authentication  or windows authentication)
- there is a Windows client to access the database from  inside the LAN
- i am  writing a  web application (Tomcat8 servlet) to access the database from  internet: in this case i want the user to type domain\username and password in the login screen to log him in

The reason why i do this is because I need to test if the supplied domain\username and password are valid. After this check is done i will connect to the db with the sa user but assign to the logged in user the proper privileges (depending on he username).
Because of an  architectural constraint I should test this by trying to conncet to the database using JDBC, so the idea is:

- create the connection  string for a windows authentication user
- try to connect

if connection is esatabilished i assume user and password are correct.

So i need to create a JDBC connection string in which i use integrated security and i explictly define a  username (DOMAIN\USER) and password. I did not find any example on how to perform this.

Comment: For integrated security, the username and password should not be specified, since it depends on the currently logged in user. For example, something like this: `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=MyApp;`. Notice there is no user name and password in connection string.

Comment: Can you not create a user with same user id and password in your SQL Server database and then specify `IntegratedSecurity=false`? So if there is a user abc\user1 in windows whom you want to allow access to the database, then create a SQL Server login with exactly same user name and password.

Comment: If you really need to connect to the SQL Server using arbitrary *Windows* credentials then you might be able to do that with jTDS but not with mssql-jdbc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>   url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.48.61\sqlexpress2008r2;
>   databaseName=MyTestDatabase;**integratedSecurity=true**;
>   **username=mydomain\eric;password=mypwd**

This will NEVER work.

> So if there is a user abc\user1 in windows whom you want to allow
>   access to the database, then create a SQL Server login with exactly
>   same user name and password.

This will never work too.

You just cannot create *SQL Server login* (opposed to *Windows login* in this context) with "`\`", it will be recognized as Windows login and you'll get an error about invalid characters.

*Trusted connection* or *Integrated security* means that it's not a server that authenticates you, but it's Windows that does it.

So in no way can you pass Windows `name` and a `password`: your account should be verified by Windows and SQL Server will only *trust* these credentials.

Comment: anyway I wrote an application in Delphi in which I can pass username and password and login  as that user, this i  did using a  DAC that allows me to  pass username and password and specifying that this is Windows authentication. LDAP works like that. anyway likely jdbc does not allow to do this. What i  mean is that i must do it with LDAP, jdbc is not the solution, this means extra coding for me